Why does php ftp_get work at command line & Filezilla but not in my index.php file?
My ftp_get command for an image started timing out on my website. This is after I confirm that the ftp_login is true. I can use the same php code at the command line, and the same credentials etc. in Filezilla, and it works. I only get a warning (PHP Warning: "ftp_get(): Opening BINARY mode data connection") from my website, no error. The issue seems to have started after Godaddy migrated my site (everything else works, permissions seem okay); they are not able to understand the problem. Perhaps there something to check on the server? Or could a coincidental change have been made on the ftp site? Thanks for any help.
Here's my php:
// connect and login to FTP server
ftp_server = "ftp.mdt.mt.gov";
ftp_user = "anonymous";
ftp_pass = "";
ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
login_result = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass);
if ($login_result == 1) 
{
    local_file = "webcam_images/Image-000150000-00-04.jpg";
    server_file = "/rwis/images/Image-150-00-ptz4.jpg";
    echo "login result true" ;
    ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY);
}

Downloading the image file works if I use php at a command line (& Filezilla), the requested image exists and I get it. Yet, the same code times out at ftp_get when run from index.php on my webpage even though the login result is true.

Since the above code works on one system but not on the other, the difference may be caused by differences of these systems. They could differ in the version, OS, perhaps even network (firewall disallowing insecure FTP, though login suggests otherwise). Could it be that you can't write to the target file?

Thanks. It used to work then it just quit working. Perhaps the ftp host changed something that stops web requests but allows php/Filezilla to still work; I'm lame on the server-side. I can use ftp_size to confirm some access from my webpage. The permissions where I'm hoping to write are 755.

@Steve 755 might not be enough when the webserver is not the owner of the target directory /rwis/images/. You should check with file_exists(),is_dir() and is_writable() if the target directory exists and can be filled by the web server.

Thanks. The file exists, I can get its size just before the ftp_get and I checked, the target directory is writeable.
